# Jquery ajax live search sometimes returns data when searchbox is cleared

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I created small jquery ajax live search .post
It works fine but when i keep deleting the value of the textbox sometimes 
when the box is completely cleared i get the last result from the search still appearing
on my search result area.

```
$("#search").live("keyup",function(){
$("#searchResult").hide();
 var searchValue = $(this).val();

 $.post("userpanel.php",{'action':'search','searchboxValue': searchValue},function(result){
  if(result == ""){
   $("#searchResult").hide();
  }
 else{
  $("#searchResult").fadeIn().html(result); 
 } 

  });               
});

<div id='searchResult'></div>
```

I tried this method but wont work. Any help please

Answer (score 0):

try adding if

```
if(searchValue!="") {    
    //fetch search results 
}
```

Comment: i tried...wont work... sometimes not everytimes...i get the last searchh result.